# Simple java script doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to create a simple script to hide and show the elements on my website, but it doesn't work. Where's i go wrong?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<style>
#hideMe { display:none; }
</style>

</head>
<body>

<button onclick="myFunction()">test</button>

<script>
var hideOrNot = true;
function myFunction() {
    if (hideOrNot == true){
        document.getElementById("hideMe").style.display:block;
        hideOrNot=false;
    }else{
        document.getElementById("hideMe").style.display:none;
        hideOrNot=true;
    }
 }
</script>
<h1 id="hideMe">text to show/hide</h1>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your code has syntax errors, which are reported on your browser console. You should always check that first before asking a question, and include the errors with your question if they don't make sense to you.

Comment: That's wrong syntax: 
document.getElementById("hideMe").style.display:block;

Please view browser console to view errors like these.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<style>
#hideMe { display:none; }
</style>

</head>
<body>

<button onclick="myFunction()">test</button>

<script>

var hideOrNot = true;

function myFunction() {

    if (hideOrNot == true){
        document.getElementById("hideMe").style.display = 'block';
        hideOrNot=false;
    } else {
        document.getElementById("hideMe").style.display = 'none';
        hideOrNot=true;
    }
}
</script>

    <h1 id="hideMe">text to show/hide</h1>

    </body>
</html>
```

Just some mistakes with display = 'block' and a missing '}' for your function :)

Answer (score 4):

There should be used `"="` instead of `":"`

Should be

```
document.getElementById("hideMe").style.display = 'block';
```

Instead of

```
document.getElementById("hideMe").style.display:block;
```

**Update**

You forgot to write closing brace `{` next to `else` condition, your code should be something like

```
var hideOrNot = true;
    function myFunction() {
    if (hideOrNot == true){
        document.getElementById("hideMe").style.display = 'block';
        hideOrNot=false;
    }else{
     //--^-- you forgot to write
        document.getElementById("hideMe").style.display = 'none';
        hideOrNot=true;
    }
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/80amwxx4/)

Comment: I tried so, but anyway it's still do nothing.

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems in your code, working **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/3ucv9L8s/)**

first the syntax,

```
document.getElementById("hideMe").style.display:block;
```

should be

```
document.getElementById("hideMe").style.display='block';
```

and you missed `{}` for else.

```
var hideOrNot = true;
function myFunction() {debugger;
if (hideOrNot){
document.getElementById("hideMe").style.display='block';
hideOrNot=false;
}else{
document.getElementById("hideMe").style.display='none';
hideOrNot=true;
}
                      }
```

Answer (score 0):

http://jsbin.com/kukibapu/1/edit

If you'd like to use JQuery, the method `$("#hideMe").toggle();` is what you want